# Activity Change on Spinner Selection

Tags: android

I have the below method.  For some reason, my activities are not changing on spinner selection change. Assuming the first value in the spinner is equal to value "1" in my switch statement.

```
public void addListener() {
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                   int position, long row_id) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            switch (position) {
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(ListCarsActivity.this, ListCarsActivity.class);

                    break;
                case 2:
                    intent = new Intent(ListCarsActivity.this, ListOwnersActivity.class);
                    break;


            }
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Have you define activity in manifest? , anything there in log?

Comment: yes, manifest looking good.

Comment: does any position work or no position is working?

Comment: None of the positions are working.

Comment: I don't think it's even running onItemSelected.  Log.d showing nothing.

Comment: Side notes: It doesn't seem that `Intent intent = getIntent();` does anything.  Where is case `0`?  No need for case `1`.  How many items are in your list?  If it's only two, it should be `case 0` and `case 1`.